# Como chamar uma viewcontrolller runtime

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

Amigos eu só preciso abrir uma ViewController , e eu estou dando bobeira, poderiam ajudar.
Quem pode ajudar .... Obrigado. .

```
LoginViewController *tela2 =
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];
[self presentViewController:tela2 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Marcio, se você já encontrou a solução por conta propria, basta responder a pergunta, como já o fez, e marcá-la como aceita, clicando no `V` ao lado esquerdo.

Answer (score 1):

Com o que você enviou parece estar tudo certo, o problema deve estar ocorrendo pelo local onde você está fazendo essa chamada, então.

Se estiver chamando esse método dentro de:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

Tente executando ele dentro do seguinte método:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

resolvido, é so criar um navigation controller.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]